# Who has the rights for adding a extra DC in a domain?

Tags: permissions

Who has the rights for adding a extra DC in a domain? Obvious the administrator got the rights, but does anyone else have the rights?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [checklist for adding a new domain controller](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc759620(v=ws.10).aspx):

> Verify that you are a member of the Domain Admins group in the domain where you will be adding the domain controller.

By default the "Administrator" AD account is in the Domain Admins group, but typically you would add additional user accounts to the Domain Admins group as well.

Answer (score 1):

Anyone who the Administrator has given the rights to.